# Wordpress responsive portfolio grid issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, portfolio

I have been having problems with a Wordpress theme where the portfolio grid doesn't seem to be spanning 100% across the page.

You can find the problem here after the 'crashes' image box - http://beta.audiopeak.net

Any help with amending this issue would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I made these changes to the **CSS** (screen.css) and it seemed to work (but with limited testing).

Let me know if they work for you.

```
.one_fourth.gallery4:hover div.thumb_content {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.one_fourth.gallery4 img{
   width: 100%;
}

.page_content_wrapper.full_width {
   width: 102%;
}
```

Comment: That seemed to have done the trick! However the image goes off the side of the page now. Not sure if we can fix that?

Comment: I discovered that - ` #portfolio_filter_wrapper.shortcode.four_cols.gallery .element, .portfolio_filter_wrapper.shortcode.four_cols.gallery .element`
uses width:24.9%

I tried changing it to 25% and it moved over, however when you resize the screen it pushes the last image down.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? I did a quick test of the CSS above on Chrome/OSX, IE9/Win7, Chrome/Win7, FF/Win7, FF/OSX, FF/Ubuntu12, Chrome/Ubuntu12 - seems to work well if you add `.page_content_wrapper.full_width {
   width: 102%;
}` to the existing (current) CSS

Comment: I've tested on MAC safari and chrome. It works, however what happens is I can move the page to the right and see this - http://i.imgur.com/LIYEpFa.jpg - Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I see, let me see what else needs tweaking then... weird I did not see it last night on OSX/chrome (but then again I was not looking at it specifically) - did you try reducing it to 101%?

Comment: Hey, yeah I did...it's pretty much the same thing! If you move the trackpad to the right it shows up.

Comment: As a temporary fix I edited the background to black and altered the hover captions. Not great...but it looks better. I've contacted the theme creator to see if he can fix it.